# How do we determine which monster joins the game?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I just played my first game and I love it! I have one question though. How is the monster that joins determined? I tried to look in the pamphlets and online and couldn't find anything. We just had the traitor choose a monster he liked. I don't know how that part works.

Comment: You're going to have to say which haunt you triggered (at least the haunt number) - every haunt has different rules (some don't even have traitors) so we'd need to know the specifics.

Comment: You look up the omen and room that triggered the haunt on [Haunt Chart](http://hexagamers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Betrayal-at-House-on-the-Hill-Haunt-Chart.jpg). It indicates who becomes the traitor, and which scenario to play. Play continues with the player after the traitor.

Answer (score 7):

The monster and everything that happens once the haunt happens is determined in the traitors and survivors handbooks. The traitors handbook instructs you on which haunt to use based on how it is triggered and there will be instructions for both sides based on each individual haunt.

Here are some simplified [rules](http://hexagamers.com/betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill-how-to-play-simplified) to help you get started better.

Comment: Thank you for you're help Joe but the link you sent be does not go into monster selection and that is the only part of that game that confuses me.

Comment: Again - you're going to have to tell us which haunt it is so we even know if there *is* a monster. The specific haunt should tell you whether there is a traitor, whether the traitor gets any special ability, whether any additional monsters spawn, and everything else.

Comment: @PrayingMantisLawyer There is no such thing as monster selection and everything that happens is spelled out in the rules.

Comment: I am not taling about any specific haunts... I want to know where it states in the handbooks or legit any where else online that states what certain monster is joining us that game.

Comment: @PrayingMantisLawyer The Haunt is what determines 'the monster' (it's not always an actual monster). The specific Haunt (and who the Traitor is) is determined by a combination of Room and Omen. It seems like you've missed important sections of the rules like the 'Haunt Roll'. Which version of the game do you have?

Comment: @PrayingMantisLawyer Monsters only ever join the game during the haunt. Haunts will tell you what monsters join and how many of them in the Traitor's Tome usually. There is no such thing as monster selection - if you mean what tokens to use to represent them, the small monster tokens are pretty much interchangeable, the large ones are labeled.

Answer (score 6):

Monsters are never selected/chosen by a player.

It is unclear if you mean Haunt selection. When the haunt is triggered; as a result of failing a haunt roll after finding an omen; look at the first 2 pages of either the Secrets of Survival book Traitor's Tome book. A chart there will tell you which Haunt you have, based on the omen and the room. There is also another list there that tells you who is the traitor, based on which haunt you have.

One you have a specific haunt, the heros and traitor each have their own rules to follow. The traitor’s rules will generally go into which tokens are needed and how to set them up. No one is just selecting which monstors they want to use.

Comment: It is probably worth emphasising as well that the traitor is also specified here as well and isn't necessarily the player that failed the role (if memory serves). I figure if they have missed the rules for haunt selection they may well miss this too.

Comment: @Chris sometimes it will say "Haunt revealer" and that means the traitor is the one who failed the roll, other times it will be based on something on the character cards, like character age or a stat, and still other times there won't be a traitor at all.

Answer (score -1):

For future players looking for the simple answer to the question:
If your end up with a HAUNT scenario that doesn’t mention monsters, you don’t need to use them this time. You haven’t done anything wrong or missed a page of instruction.

The scenario likely has some other way to torment heroes, or a different goal for the player(s).

The instruction book fails to mention this.